# How to force segments merge in Elasticsearch 5?

Tags: elasticsearch, optimization, elasticsearch-5

I'm working with Elasticsearch 5.2.2 and I would like to fully merge the segments of my index after an intensive indexing operation.

I'm using the following rest API in order to merge all the segments:

```
http://localhost:9200/my_index/_forcemerge
```

(I've tried also to add *max_num_segments=1* in the POST request.)

And ES replies with:

```
{
  "_shards": {
    "total": 16,
    "successful": 16,
    "failed": 0
  }
}
```

Note that my_index is composed by 16 shards.

But when I ask for node stats (http://localhost:9200/_nodes/stats) it replies with:

```
segments: {
    count: 64,
    [...]
}
```

So it seems that all the shards are split into 4 segments (64/16 = 4). In fact, an "ls" on the data directory confirms that there are 4 segments per shards:

```
~# ls /var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/ym_5_99nQrmvTlR_2vicDA/0/index/
_0.cfe      _0.cfs      _0.si       _1.cfe      _1.cfs      _1.si       _2.cfe      _2.cfs      _2.si       _5.cfe      _5.cfs      _5.si       segments_6  write.lock
```

And no concurrent merges are running (http://localhost:9200/_nodes/stats):

```
merges: {
    current: 0,
    [...]
}
```

And all the force_merge requests have been completed (http://localhost:9200/_nodes/stats):

```
force_merge: {
    threads: 1,
    queue: 0,
    active: 0,
    rejected: 0,
    largest: 1,
    completed: 3
}
```

I hadn't this problem with ES 2.2.

Who knows how to fully merge these segments?

Thank you all!

Comment: were you able to find the answer to this question?

Comment: I had the same problem and solved this by pausing indexing against my cluster while running the merge. When doing that, I was able to get my segment size down to max_num_segments on ES 6.x.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether your problem solved. just post here to let other people know.

this should be a bug. you can see following issue. use empty json body can make it work.
https://github.com/TravisTX/elasticsearch-head-chrome/issues/16